# Magento 2.3.2 to Magento 2.3.5-p2 upgrad frontend display widget and mageTranslationDictionary error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p2

After upgrade Magento 2.3.2 to Magento 2.3.5-p2 frontend side display widget and mageTranslationDictionary error.

I have run all command still not resolve.

[image]

Thank in advance,

Comment: try to remove pub/static content and generated then run deploy command basically there are some js missing

Comment: @Pramod I have already tried that

Comment: did u got any solution

Comment: Yes It's caused issue because of third party cache.

Comment: @SweetyMasmiya how did you fix the issue? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I am getting mageTranslationDictionary error on each page during page load, When we  refresh the page then the issue is not showing